# Why do I get ony gray boxes in the toolbar of my win32 gui program instead of the icon images?

Tags: c++, winapi, toolbar

I am building a win32 gui for my usb controlled logic analyzer and there I want to implement a toolbar.
So I picked up a tutorial and tried this code in Code::Blocks. It worked fine with the exception that
the toolbar icons are replaced with gray boxes. What is the problem ??
The code seems rather Ok since I could play with separators and could see their effect.
First I expected an bitmap problem of my toolbar.bmp image and created it with a different tool - same result.
I would appreciate any suggestion ... 
Martin

Oh - I found that the problem is related to TBBUTTON tbb.iBitmap. If I set it to 0 I see the first image (however not quite correct). How to set this value correct ?

This is my code:

```
// Win32 Tutorial (Toolbars)
// Alan Baylis 2004

#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include "resource.h"

const char ClassName[] = "MainWindowClass";
HWND hTool;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc( HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam );


INT WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR  lpCmdLine, INT  nCmdShow ) {
    InitCommonControls();
    WNDCLASSEX    wc;

    wc.cbSize           = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style            = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc      = (WNDPROC)WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra       = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra       = 0;
    wc.hInstance        = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon            = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON));
    wc.hIconSm          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON));
    wc.hCursor          = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground    = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wc.lpszMenuName     = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName    = ClassName;

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Failed To Register The Window Class.", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return 0;
    }

    HWND    hWnd;

    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, ClassName, "Toolbars",
                          WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                          CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                          240, // width
                          120, // height
                          NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    if (!hWnd) {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Creation Failed.", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return 0;
    }
    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    MSG    Msg;

    while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }
    return Msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc( HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam ) {
    switch (Msg) {
        case WM_CREATE: {
            TBADDBITMAP tbab;
            TBBUTTON tbb[3];
            hTool = CreateWindowEx(0, TOOLBARCLASSNAME, (LPSTR)NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                   hWnd, (HMENU)IDTB_TOOLBAR, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);

            if (!hTool) {
                MessageBox(NULL, "Tool Bar Failed.", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
                return 0;
            }
            // Send the TB_BUTTONSTRUCTSIZE message, which is required for backward compatibility.
            SendMessage(hTool, TB_BUTTONSTRUCTSIZE, (WPARAM)sizeof(TBBUTTON), 0);
            SendMessage(hTool, TB_SETBITMAPSIZE, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)MAKELONG(20, 20));

            tbab.hInst = (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_HINSTANCE);
            tbab.nID   = IDR_TOOLBAR1;
            SendMessage(hTool, TB_ADDBITMAP, (WPARAM) 1, (LPARAM) &tbab);

            ZeroMemory(tbb, sizeof(tbb));
            tbb[0].iBitmap = 20;
            tbb[0].idCommand = ID_BUT1_OPEN;
            tbb[0].fsState = TBSTATE_ENABLED;
            tbb[0].fsStyle = TBSTYLE_BUTTON;

            tbb[1].fsStyle = TBSTYLE_SEP;

            tbb[2].iBitmap = 21;
            tbb[2].idCommand = ID_BUT2_SAVE;
            tbb[2].fsState = TBSTATE_ENABLED;
            tbb[2].fsStyle = TBSTYLE_BUTTON;

            SendMessage(hTool, TB_ADDBUTTONS, 3, (LPARAM)&tbb);
            ShowWindow(hTool, SW_SHOW);
        }
        break;
        case WM_COMMAND: {
            switch(LOWORD(wParam)) {
                case ID_BUT1_OPEN: {
                    MessageBox(NULL, "Toolbar Button One", "Success", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
                }
                break;
                case ID_BUT2_SAVE: {
                    MessageBox(NULL, "Toolbar Button Two", "Success", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
                }
                break;
            }
            return 0;
        }
        break;
        case WM_SIZE:
            SendMessage(hTool, TB_AUTOSIZE, 0, 0);
        break;
        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
        default:
            return (DefWindowProc(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

resource.h

```
#define IDI_ICON        101
#define IDTB_TOOLBAR    200
#define IDR_TOOLBAR1    200
#define ID_BUT1_OPEN    201
#define ID_BUT2_SAVE    202
```

resource.rc

```
#include "resource.h"

IDI_ICON ICON "icon.ico"

// Toolbar
IDR_TOOLBAR1 TOOLBAR DISCARDABLE  16, 16
BEGIN
    BUTTON      ID_BUT1_OPEN
       SEPARATOR
    BUTTON      ID_BUT2_SAVE
END
IDR_TOOLBAR1 BITMAP "toolbar1.bmp"
```

Comment: You need to set the `iBitmap` member for *each* of the `TBBUTTON` structures in the array - each to the corresponding index in your bitmap. If your images in that bitmap are in order, then the `iBitmap` values will be: `0`, `1`, ... etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - Thank you, this solved the problem. I had tried this before with no success - reason was inconsistents between TB_SETBITMAPSIZE in the cpp file and IDR_TOOLBAR1 TOOLBAR DISCARDABLE  size in the rc file. Thank you for your help